# Passing value in Partail View and retrieve

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view in mvc3 for rendering tbody content.

So how can I pass count vale in partial view and get counter value in my Serial Number column

Comment: <table id="tbl">
    <tr><th>Sr No.</th>
        <th>Ticket Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="tblbody">
@if (Model.TicketList != null && Model.TicketList.Count() > 0)
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var item in Model.TicketList)
            {
                count++;                
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_TicketSearch.cshtml", item)                
            }
        }    </tbody>
</table>my partial view append tr for model which contain serial column,my problem is how to pass incremented row number in partial view

Answer (score 0):

PartialViews can have Models assigned to them just like regular views:

```
@model Namespace.SubNamespace.Folder.ClassName
```

Then, you can call Html.Partial and pass a new instance of that model:

```
@Html.Partial("ViewName", new ClassName() {//set values here});
```

If you do this, you can calculate the number of rows before the partial call and use that elsewhere:

```
@{
    var numRows = dataSource.Rows.Count(); //use whatever count method you like
}
```

Meaning you can calculate the row count and set it as part of the PartialView's view model:

```
@{
    var numRows = dataSource.Rows.Count(); //use whatever count method you like
}
@Html.Partial("ViewName", new ClassName() {RowCount = numRows});
```

Comment: <table id="tbl">
    <tr><th>Sr No.</th>
        <th>Ticket Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="tblbody">
@if (Model.TicketList != null && Model.TicketList.Count() > 0)
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var item in Model.TicketList)
            {
                count++;                
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_TicketSearch.cshtml", item)                
            }
        }    </tbody>
</table>my partial view append tr for model which contain serial column,my problem is how to pass incremented row number in partial view